# Verdaccio on IIS on server 2008 r2

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, verdaccio

I have setup the verdaccio on IIS on windows 10 and it works perfectly fine. But when I did the same process on server 2008 r2 it opens the page but then suddenly some runtime error and then shows blank page. On console I see some runtime errors on script 1002.

Verdaccio : 4.12.0
node : 12.7.0
python : 2.7

Comment: Sorry to be pinging this late. I'm trying to setup verdaccio on my windows 11 machine and it just doesn't work. Keep getting a HTTP Error 500.1002 - Internal Server Error. Can you please let me know what steps you took to make it work? Thanks

I have started a discussion here - https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/discussions/4467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although after a lot of try and error. Changing verdaccio version to 4.4.4 worked for me.
To install verdaccio@4.4.4 with python 2.7 we can run following command;

```
npm i verdaccio@4.4.4 --python=python2.7
```